# "System.Windows.Forms.PlaceholderTextBox, Text: " Error when inserting data in MySQL database using myPHPAdmin

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin, mysql-connector

## Am trying to capture data from textbox to save it to mysql database but the field is <kbd>System.Windows.Forms.PlaceholderTextBox, Text: Adm</kbd>

## This is my Buttonsave click event save

Dim theFirstname As String = firstName.Text

```
type here
```

```
    Dim theEmail As String = emailCom.Text
    Dim username As String = userName2.Text
    Dim thePassword As String = passWord2.Text

    If theFirstname.Trim() = "" Or theEmail.Trim() = "" Or username.Trim() = "" Or thePassword.Trim() = "" Then

        MessageBox.Show("One Or More Fields Are Empty", "Missing Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)

    ElseIf Usernamexist(username) Then

        MessageBox.Show("This Username Already Exists, Choose Another One", "Duplicate Username", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    Else

        
        connection.Open()

        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO authentic (firstname, email, username, password) VALUES (@firstname,@email,@username,@password)", connection)
        
        command.Parameters.Add("@firstname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstName
        command.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailCom
        command.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName2
        command.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passWord2

        

        connection.Open()

        

        MessageBox.Show("Registration Completed Successfully", "User Added", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        connection.Close()

        If command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then

            MessageBox.Show("Registration Completed Successfully", "User Added", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            connection.Close()

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("Something Happen", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            connection.Close()

        End If


        firstName.Text = ""
            emailCom.Text = ""
            userName2.Text = ""
            passWord2.Text = ""

            accLogin.Visible = True
            createAcc.Visible = False

        End If
```

This is what am getting at the moment

[image]

anyone with an idea how to go about this?

Faithfully
Moe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the answer yourself, in the first few lines of your code.

Where you set the values in the parameters, none of the lines are using the value, they are getting the object.

> command.Parameters.Add("@firstname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstName
> command.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailCom
> command.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName2
> command.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passWord2

Change to:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@firstname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstName.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailCom.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName2.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passWord2.Text
```

Each of the lines has a **.Text** at the end to extract the value of the object.